# The Classical Theory of Fields: Surface Integral of Poynting Vector Vanishes at Infinity on page 76

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory, poynting-vector

I am reading the section *Energy density and energy flux* in *Chapter 4. The Electromagnetic Field Equations* of Landau's The Classical Theory of Fields (third revised English edition). On page 76 after equation 31.3, the book says

If the integral extends over all space, then the surface integral (of the Poynting vector) vanishes

I am not quite sure if this is a correct statement as we know that in general when charge and current distribution is changing with time, the $E$ and $H$ fields produced decay as $\frac{1}{r}$ (in the radiation zone), and so $E \times H$ decay as $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ giving rise to non vanishing surface integral of the Poynting vector even when we let the surface extend to infinity. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Formally it seems correct that electromagnetic radiation can not leave the universe... so I don't see an immediate problem with it from a physical perspective. If we experimentally put an amount of energy into a volume of spacetime with an antenna, then that energy will spread out at the speed of light. The further away we are, the longer it will take for it to arrive (for the Poynting vector to become non-zero). If we go to infinity, then it will take an infinite amount of time for it to arrive. What does it mean? It means that maybe one should not treat electrodynamics like electrostatics.

Comment: @Flattermann the objection is that the surface integral need not vanish.

Comment: @JánLalinský I don't think it does, except at infinity, which puts the physics into the infinite future. Did I misunderstand? The answer by hyportnex seems to agree with my handwaving argument, unless I misunderstand it as well. There are a number of problems in electrodynamics where the "mechanical" application of "electro/magnetostatics physics at infinity" calculations (which are explicitly non-relativistic) seems to run into problems with the finite speed of light. This seems to be one of these situations. Just my gut feeling.

Comment: @FlatterMann See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! In the case of radiating sources in the finite both $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf H$ are $\mathcal O(R^{-1})$ and the integral $\oint \mathbf E \times \mathbf H \cdot d\mathbf f$ is finite as $R\to \infty$. In fact, this is the basis of all radio communications link budget calculations because the total integrated far field radiation *is* the amount transmitted...Wow, an error in Landau&Lifshitz!

But wait a minute, maybe Landau is talking about placing a sphere that is because the speed of propagation being finite is *outside* the field, i.e., before they get there, in that case of course both $ \mathbf E$ and $ \mathbf H$ are zero there and the surface integral is zero too! This must be it, so Landau&Lifshitz is right again...

Comment: Ah I get what you are saying! Thanks for pointing out! If we only start having nonzero current and charge distribution after some point in time, then at any given time, we can always find null field distribution in the region sufficiently far away from the source distribution and if we place our integration surface there, the surface integral of Poynting vector evaluates to zero. So I guess the author when making the statement that the surface integral vanishes as the surface extends to infinity is assuming that there is a point in time before which there is no sources at all.

Comment: Exactly. You could not do this trick in the frequency domain - time harmonic dependence $e^{j\omega t}$ version of the Poynting theorem that is calculated for/with the complex amplitudes, $\hat S=\hat E\times \hat H^*$, because that lasts from $t=-\infty$ to $-\infty$, but of course in that formulation $\hat S$ is the time averaged flux. I have never seen an *error* in L&L, just some occasional sloppy or obscure writing; this certainly is one.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the if-then statement is incorrect in general. The surface integral can be non-zero in infinity, and it can also be zero at infinity. We can't check this directly so we should not claim it is either way. In the infinity, there could be pure radiation field (not connected to sources) or there could be advanced fields of the sources.

L&L probably meant a situation where all the field is retarded field due to charges and currents in some sphere, and there is a larger sphere outside of which the field is electrostatic or at least the Poynting flux is zero. This is a very specific set of assumptions, which should have been stated.

Also, in the derivation L&L implicitly assume that particles are not points, but extended charged distributions whose self-action is negligible (so that electric field is uniform over the particle, and the work per unit time of EM field can be expressed as sum $\sum e\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf E$). This is problematic, because extended charged distributions do act on themselves during accelerated motion (this is often estimated by the so-called Lorentz-Abraham-Dirac force).

All this has an interesting consequence, that the equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\{\int \frac{E^2+H^2}{8\pi} dV + \sum \mathscr{E}_{kin}\bigg\} = 0
$$

is not necessarily valid. In general, it is not correct to base derivations on this idea that Poynting EM energy plus kinetic energy of the universe is conserved.

Comment: There is IMHO no volume in which the physical field is ever "electrostatic". Electrostatics is a non-relativistic approximation in which the speed of light is assumed to be infinite. In practice we are either trading temporal or spatial scale for this approximation, i.e. we have to wait "long enough" or we have to work in a "small enough" neighborhood, but we can't have both at the same time. Maybe that's just the experimentalist oversimplifying, so please don't take offense with my remarks. There is none intended. I am simply trying to understand this intuitively.

Comment: By electrostatic I mean the Coulomb field, with no magnetic field. That is one particular way how the surface integral may vanish. We can't be sure of what happens in the infinity, it may vanish, but it need not.

Comment: Thanks @JánLalinský for the sharing your thoughts and elaboration! I agree that L&L should have explicitly stated the assumption that it is considering the retarded field (i.e., the E and H calculated from the retarded potentials) and that those radiating sources are not present at all before a particular instant in time, which would have avoided any confusion.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thank you for your input to this discussion:) I think your first comment is more or less in line with that of hyportnex. However, even in electrodynamical case the surface integral of the Poynting vector can be nonzero in the limit of extending the surface to infinity (this limiting process should be done at a fixed instant in time) if radiating sources are present throughout the entire time up to the time when you evaluate the limit of the surface integral

Comment: and electrostatic situation can be thought of as having constant (with respect to time) current and charge distribution throughout the entire history.

Comment: @JánLalinský About the self force on the radiating sources...Is this force exerted by the electromagnetic field at the location of the sources? Let's say we have a continuous charge distribution rho(x,t), which is radiating. Suppose that the total field dist is E(x,t) and B(x,t). Is the self force at the point x at time t equal to rho(x,t)*delta*(E(x,t)+v(x,t) x B(x,t)), where delta is the infinitesimal volume at x? Please educate me on this as I am not familiar with the topic of self force yet.

Comment: @Mark_tt yes, self-force is due to EM force of a body on itself.

Comment: @Mark_tt I think you are getting to the point here: extending a surface to infinity at one point in time is a mathematical, but not a physical operation. It violates relativity. It would also require sources that have been radiating for an infinite length of time (i.e. with an infinite total amount of energy). Personally I don't think that's a good way of doing relativistic physics, not even in theory. That's an opinion, of course.